# Angular ng-blur function calling on page load only

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am saving details on ng-blur, but that function is getting called on page load only. I don't know what is the reason behind it. Is that the expected behavior of ng-blur or i am doing some thing wrong.
here is my code.

```
<input type="text" class="detail-input" ng-if="controlDetail" ng-blur="saveControlDetails()">
```

Anyone please help me
[image]

Comment: can you produce a snipplet

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WS5RLUyQ1aogMgtrUs7A?p=preview here it is working fine and in my project it is working on page load only. What could be the reason.

Comment: Show me your script code

Comment: Plunk work as expected.

Comment: yes, in plunker it is working as expected. but in my project it is calling function on page load. What could be the reason

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?  Are you running code on initialization?

Comment: No, i am not running that function on initialization and checked for errors so many times

Comment: can you send a screenshot of console.May it can help us.

Comment: I have attached screenshot

Comment: May be a different Angular version on plnkr and your local.

Comment: same 1.5.8 version of angular in both local and plunker

Comment: If i use same function to 2 ng-blur's will it call on initilization

Comment: If i remove, ng-blur function or ng-model in that particular in put, it will not call